# How to compute average correlation coefficient per year after DCC-GARCH estimation in R?

Tags: r, time-series, correlation, forecasting

At the moment, I have fitted a DCC-GARCH model to my financial returns data and estimated the correlation coefficients by means of this reproducible code:

```
library(rugarch)
library(rmgarch)
data(dji30retw)
Dat = dji30retw[, 1:8, drop = FALSE]
uspec = ugarchspec(mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0,0)), variance.model = list(garchOrder = c(1,1), model = "eGARCH"), distribution.model = "norm")
spec1 = dccspec(uspec = multispec(replicate(8, uspec)), dccOrder = c(1,1),  distribution = "mvnorm")
fit1 = dccfit(spec1, data = Dat)
print(fit1)
r1=rcor(fit1, type="cor")
```

Now, I need to create a data-frame which consists of 1 column that includes the average of the correlation coefficients per week. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Average of which correlation coefficient exactly? You have weekly covariance matrices, so it's not clear.

Comment: Each of the matrices in `r1` is 8x8, implying that there are 28 unique correlation coefficients. So which 8 then?

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem?

Comment: Right, one for each element of `r1`. For instance, the coefficient corresponding to `r1[, , 1]` would be `mean(r1[, , 1][upper.tri(r1[, , 1])])`.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like what you want is

```
Dat$meancor <- apply(r1, 3, function(r) mean(r[upper.tri(r)]))
```

giving

```
head(Dat, 2)
#                      AA          AXP           BA         BAC           C        CAT         CVX          DD   meancor
# 1987-03-27 -0.005952399 -0.007942854 -0.008866429 -0.03119837 -0.02586351 0.01587335 -0.02204814 0.006389798 0.3786852
# 1987-04-03  0.005952399 -0.025849581 -0.010230268  0.00000000 -0.01762160 0.04113691  0.06324389 0.035457312 0.375325
```

To achieve that, `apply` goes over the third dimension of `r1` (over each correlation matrix)`, takes the upper triangular elements and averages them.